# Centripetal force to charge carriers in curved conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, conductors, centripetal-force

> Suppose we applied an emf across a circular conductor, then the electrons inside the conductors would drift to the positive side

But how does the electrons get centripetal force?

Firstly, I considered force on electrons due to the electric field applied due to emf but that comes out to be constant as :

$$f=Vq/l$$

where $l$ is the length of the conductor.

If this would be the case, then electron would only move in a circle of fixed radius , but the current also flows even if I bend the wire highly.

I am thinking that this happens due to some magnetic field caused by the moving charges itself.

**My question(s) :**

What force does gives the charges necessary centripetal force to move in any curves with same current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of surface charges is critical for understanding the way that ordinary circuits function. In the specific case of your question on every bend in a wire there is an increased amount of surface charge. This provides the force needed for the turn. This is explained in further depth by Jackson’s famous paper: Surface charges on circuit wires and resistors play three roles

https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.18112

Specifically, Jackson says

> In general, the conductors of a current‐carrying circuit must have nonuniform surface charge densities on them (1) to maintain the potential around the circuit, (2) to provide the electric field in the space outside the conductors, and (3) to assure the confined flow of current.

Your question is a subset of point 3. Surface charges guide and direct the current flow along the wire, providing all of the forces needed to do so. This includes centripetal forces as you asked, but also longitudinal forces to change the drift velocity e.g. when the wire gets thicker or thinner.